# Visio Professional 2013 doesn't support UML deployment diagram. How to work with Visio 2013 to make one?

Tags: uml, visio

I'm using Visio 2013 to make UML deployment diagram. Unfortunately it doesn't support - it doesn't have any default template etc. Since last 10 hours and more I've been searching for some right tool that helps me make such diagrams. I didn't find any helpful tool yet. Please guide me.

Comment: http://dia-installer.de/

Answer (score 15):

If you want to create a deployment diagram that is similar to the ones you could make in earlier versions of Visio, I'd recommend going to [this site](http://softwarestencils.com/uml/index.html#Visio2013) and downloading their UML stencils for 2013.

You could also look at branching out a bit and using something like [Archimate](http://www.opengroup.org/subjectareas/enterprise/archimate). You can look at section 9.4.14 in [this document](http://pubs.opengroup.org/architecture/archimate-doc/ts_archimate/chap9.html) to see an example of a deployment/implementation viewpoint with Archimate. Orbus has a free download of the Archimate 2.0 stencils [here](http://www.orbussoftware.com/downloads/free-visio-stencils/archimate-visio-stencil-and-template). I think you have to go through a free registration, but they won't spam you.

Comment: Thanks for the UML stencils!